# Vertical offset for buttons in horizontal row

Tags: html, css, button

**Problem description:**
Despite equal top-margins of the button elements, there is a vertical offset between them.

If the margin-top: attribute is changed, the whole row of buttons moves, instead of one element.

**I have tried:**

- different display-attributes (`display: inline;` & `display: inline-block;`)
- `position: relative;`

**The next solution I would think of:**

Assign the attribute `position:absolute;` to the buttons and then define the margins separately for each element. 
But that would not be an elegant solution (i would look for one, if you got ideas).

**Picture with the described problem:**

[image]

```css
.VPcalc {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

div input {
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

button#btnR1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkblue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

button#btnR2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkred;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

button#btnR1:hover,
button#btnR2:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

div input#tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

div button#factor,
div button#calculation {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

span#f1,
span#t1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="VPcalc">
  <button id="btnR1" onClick="myFunction()">Neue Zahl</button>
  <button id="btnR2" onClick="auswerten()">Auswerten</button>

  <button id="factor"><span id="f1"></span></button>
  <button id="calculation"><span id="t1" ></span></button>
  <input type="number" id="tag"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to use Flexbox for this:

```css
.VPcalc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

div input {
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

button#btnR1{
  
  background-color: darkblue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

button#btnR2{
  background-color: darkred;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

button#btnR1:hover, button#btnR2:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

div input#tag{
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

div button#factor, div button#calculation{
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

span#f1, span#t1{
  font-size: 12px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="VPcalc"> 
  <button id="btnR1" onClick="myFunction()">Neue Zahl</button> 
  <button id="btnR2" onClick="auswerten()">Auswerten</button> 
  <button id="factor" ><span id="f1"></span></button>
  <button id="calculation"><span id="t1" ></span></button>
  <input type="number" id="tag" ></input>
</div>
```

There are options for spacing out those buttons. I've just centered them with a gap, but you might prefer something like `justify-content: space-between` etc. instead of the gap.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to position things with margin. The modern approach is with flexbox.

Also, write CSS for *classes*, not IDs, so it's reusable, and simplify by targeting like elements within a container. Use class names that describe the feature they add to the element.

```css
.VPcalc {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.VPcalc input {
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.VPcalc button,
.VPcalc input {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
}

.VPcalc button {
  padding: 4px 0;
}

.btn-blue {
  background: darkblue;
}

.btn-red {
  background: darkred;
}

.btn-blue:hover,
.btn-red:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.VPcalc input,
.VPcalc btn {
  background-color: white;
}

.VPcalc span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="VPcalc">
  <button id="btnR1" class="btn-blue" onClick="myFunction()">Neue Zahl</button>
  <button id="btnR2" class="btn-red" onClick="auswerten()">Auswerten</button>

  <button id="factor"><span id="f1"></span></button>
  <button id="calculation"><span id="t1" ></span></button>
  <input type="number" id="tag" />
</div>
```